# Can I use the free Microsoft C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 to build conda packages?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Is it possible to build binary conda python packages using the [free Microsoft C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)?

I installed the compiler on my Windows 7 machine, but when I try a conda build (e.g. conda build pyproj from https://github.com/ioos/conda-recipes/tree/master/pyproj), I get:

```
C:\Anaconda64\conda-bld\work\pyproj-1.9.3>set USERPROFILE=C:\Users\rsignell

C:\Anaconda64\conda-bld\work\pyproj-1.9.3>REM ===== end generated header =====
C:\Anaconda64\conda-bld\work\pyproj-1.9.3>"C:\Anaconda64\envs\_build\python.exe"
 setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 14, in <module>
    objects = cc.compile(['nad2bin.c', 'src/pj_malloc.c'])
  File "C:\Anaconda64\envs\_build\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 473, in
compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Anaconda64\envs\_build\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in
initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Anaconda64\envs\_build\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 271, in
query_vcvarsall
    raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

C:\Anaconda64\conda-bld\work\pyproj-1.9.3>if errorlevel 1 exit 1
Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c bld.bat
```

My conda info is:

```
c:\Users\rsignell\Documents\GitHub\conda-recipes>conda info
Current conda install:

             platform : win-64
        conda version : 3.8.1
  conda-build version : 1.10.0
       python version : 2.7.8.final.0
     requests version : 2.5.1
     root environment : C:\Anaconda64  (writable)
  default environment : C:\Anaconda64
     envs directories : C:\Anaconda64\envs
        package cache : C:\Anaconda64\pkgs
         channel URLs : http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                        http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False
```

Comment: Look in `msvc9compiler.py` and see where it's looking for `vcvarsall.bat`. You may need to define an environment variable (or run some compiler-provided script to get it defined).

Comment: I'm guessing conda build needs to be updated to work with this. They probably changed the location of vcvarsall.bat.

Comment: Okay, there are 3 files named `msvc9compiler.py` in my anaconda distribution, and I found the `vcvarsall.bat` file got installed at `C:\Users\rsignell\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\vcvarsall.bat`.    So what should I do now?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it with a patch like this:

1. set an environment variable (be sure to use your own name):

   `VS90COMNTOOLS=C:\Users\joost\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0`
2. patch the file C:\Users\joost\Anaconda\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py

   ```
       if not os.path.isdir(productdir):
           log.debug("%s is not a valid directory" % productdir)
           return None
   ```

   into:

   ```
   if not os.path.isdir(productdir):
       productdir = toolsdir
       if not os.path.isdir(productdir):
           log.debug("%s is not a valid directory" % productdir)
           return None
   ```

Done!
The bug is that the `vcvarsall.bat` file was searched at `..\..\VC` dir that isn't there in the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 27.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me.  It still can't find `vcvarsall.bat`.  If I look at the build log (https://gist.github.com/rsignell-usgs/7d9c92508358844151c4) the only thing that looks a bit odd is that something is setting VS90COMNTOOLS back to a value that is several directories up.  (https://gist.github.com/rsignell-usgs/7d9c92508358844151c4#file-gistfile1-txt-L31). Could that be the problem?

Comment: It is not solving the problem! Did not work for me either.